# what does differencing a stationary time series do?

Tags: time-series, differences

I am trying to understand overdifferencing, if I were to first difference a stationary time series, would that time series remain stationary? Would it become white noise? Does it actually make the time series less stable?

Comment: A recent thread on overdifferencing appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250728.  I believe it might answer all your questions.

Comment: @whuber Saw your answer to the referenced question.  Did you get the bounty?  The question was about iid variables.  It is a special case of an uncorrelated time series that is stationary.   My intuitive thinking is that it adds spurious trends to the time series and that could explain the instability .  For the OPs benefit I do not think the differenced series would look anything like white noise.

Comment: @Michael: I think you're right.  Look at it in reverse.  If a differenced series were white noise, then that original series would be integrated white noise--that is, Brownian Motion--which obviously is not stationary.  BTW, that bounty lasts another 5 days.  If I were the OP I wouldn't award it until the last moment, because it might continue attracting attention and bring in additional replies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High autocorrelation when taking the L-th order of difference of a sequence of independent random numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250728/high-autocorrelation-when-taking-the-l-th-order-of-difference-of-a-sequence-of-i)